# Distance between connected components

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wanted to know if there is some inbuilt function to get distance between different connected components in MATLAB. I am using `bwlabel` to get the various connected components.Is there some way to get the distance between these connected components?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to locate the centroid of each connected component and then apply [pdist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) to find the pairwise distance between each of them.

Simple example:

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Create logical array
BW = logical ([1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
               1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
               1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
               1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
               1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
               1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
               1     1     1     0     0     1     1     0
               1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0])

%/ Call regionprops and concatenate centroid coordinates
S = regionprops(bwlabel(BW,4),'Centroid')

Centroids = vertcat(S.Centroid)

%// Measure pairwise distance
D = pdist(Centroids,'euclidean')
```

Outputs in the Command Window:

```
BW =

     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0


S = 

3x1 struct array with fields:

    Centroid


Centroids =

    2.0000    4.5000
    5.5000    2.5000
    6.8000    5.8000


D =

    4.0311    4.9729    3.5468
```